# GLSL shader compilation fails becuse of non-existent character

Tags: c++, glsl

I've been following the LearnOpenGL.com tutorial in C++, but since I didn't like to manually hard-code the shaders into the code I wrote a function that reads the shaders from a file:

```
const char* ReadShader(const char* p_ShaderLocation)
{
    std::ifstream ShaderStream;
    std::stringstream Buffer;

    ShaderStream.open(p_ShaderLocation);

    if (!ShaderStream)
    {
        std::cout << "File: " << p_ShaderLocation << " can't be opened!" << '\n';
        return 0;
    }

    if (ShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        Buffer << ShaderStream.rdbuf();
        ShaderStream.close();
        return Buffer.str().c_str();
    }
    else if (!ShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File: " << p_ShaderLocation << " can't be read!" << '\n';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried it the first time and it gave me this compilation error:

```
ERROR: Vertex Shader Compilaton Failed
ERROR: 0:2: 'Ç' : unexpected token
ERROR: 0:2: '' : compilation terminated
ERROR: 2 compilation errors.  No code generated.


ERROR: Fragment Shader Compilaton Failed
ERROR: 0:2: '' :  syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

I've no idea whats causing this, but I think it has something to do with the ReadShader function.
Also the shaders are the exact same as the shaders from the tutorial.

Comment: `Buffer` is locally scoped, so you're returning a dangling pointer via `return Buffer.str().c_str();`

Comment: Try to minimize the use of pointers in modern C++. You return a dangling pointer (UB), which is obviously not good, but if it were a valid pointer, there would still be the question of who is responsible for it.  Who has to free the memory again. And if you know that you have to do it after the function call, it is till extra work to write that. Returning a `std::string` would save you from all those headaches.

Comment: A good compiler would [warn you](https://godbolt.org/z/sqdvx9qGo) about this. *"**error:** returning address of local temporary object"*

Comment: Checking if `!ShaderStream.is_open()` after checking if `ShaderStream.is_open()` looks redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
const char* ReadShader(const char* p_ShaderLocation) 
{
    return Buffer.str().c_str();
}
```

do

```
std::string ReadShader(const char* p_ShaderLocation)
{
    return { Buffer.str() };
}
```

See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str

> **Notes**
>
> The copy of the underlying string returned by `str` is a temporary object that will be destructed at the end of the expression, so directly calling `c_str()` on the result of `str()` (for example in `auto *ptr = out.str().c_str();`) results in a dangling pointer.

Once you have the shader code as a string object, you can pass the code to the gl function like this:

```
auto shader_src = ReadShader();
const char *shader_src_str = shader_src.c_str();
GLint shader_src_len = shader_src.length();
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shader_src_str, &shader_src_len /* or nullptr */);
```